# Facebook Like Button and Getting Users UID in the Link URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

Trying to demystify the Like button as of December 2011.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Have 2 questions:

1. How do I include a "src" and "ref" paramater in the URL that the user is liking? I realize this is well documented, yet I couldn't actually do it in my testing... please provide an example of this.
2. How can I stuff the UID of user that is liking it onto the link that they are liking for example, if they like http://example.com, I'd like the link to be formed http://example.com?src=fb&ref=1234567

Please point me to any examples, thanks!

Comment: About second: you cannot, since you know nothing about current user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you have the user-id.
You can specify the `ref` parameter as follows, (XFBML version)

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/fblikepage.php" 
     send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"
     ref="<?php echo $userid; ?>"
>
</fb:like>
```

There is **no way you can specify the src parameter,** it'll be automatically appended by Facebook, when you specify the ref parameter as shown above. The url will look like this on Facebook : `http://www.example.com/fblikepage.php?fb_ref=xyz&fb_source=profile_oneline`. See the following part from the documentation.

> ref - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). **The ref attribute causes two parameters to be added to the referrer URL** when a user clicks a link from a stream story about a Like action:
>   fb_ref - the ref parameter
>   fb_source - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

Ofcourse the fb_source parameter will vary according to where the url is shown on Facebook and that will be done by Facebook. If you want to know whether a user is visiting through Facebook or not, you can just see if the fb_source parameter is there in the `$_REQUEST` variable, something like this:

```
<?php
 /* lots of code */
 if(isset($_REQUEST['fb_source'])){
   // we know the current user is visiting through some link on Facebook, so you can do whatever you wanted here
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you said it yourself it is really well documented ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)) and quite difficult to explain in a way more simple then in the documentation. However, here is an example of a like button (look for the ref parameter inside of the src string):

   ```
   <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;send=false&amp;ref=top_left&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35&amp;appId=YOUR_APP_ID" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
   ```

   If you ask more specifically, I'll try to help further.
2. You must have the user ID before loading the iframe of the like button. Then you can stuff the ID into the link using a server side script. A `http://example.com<?php echo ( "?ref=" . $userid); ?>` would do. You do not need any additional src parameter; if a user klicks a link back to your website, Facebook will pass back both the ref value as a fb_ref parameter and a fb_source parameter in the referrer URL. 
   Example: http://example.com?fb_ref=top_left&fb_source=profile_oneline
   Once again I'd like to recommend to go through the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

   What problems did you have during your testing? Could you please update your question with a code sample?

Comment: I see how to do it, yet I can't actually make it work in production... the link always produces the root-url http://example.com .. I'm following exactly the format of the documentation... please provide a working sample.